# Fixes for Internet connection problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

I purchased a laptop in December 2013 that came with Windows 8. I've been having multiple Internet connection issues since the day I purchased it, including:

- I am disconnected from Internet at about one-minute intervals.
- When I *am* connected, web pages will not load most of the time, due to being "interrupted by a change in the network connection", according to Chrome.
- Internet connection will often become "limited" with the yellow warning triangle icon for hours (and in one case, days) on end.

I am nearly certain this is not a problem with my router or network settings because my parents own the exact same model and have had none of these connection problems, as well as on any other device. Also, the same things occur when I connect my laptop to other places such as friends' houses and cafés.

I've tried almost every solution that I've found online and even HP technical support has been trying to pin the blame on my network. However, none of these solutions have worked.

This is a very awful situation to be in, because I can't download anything, and it could take up to 30 minutes of constant refreshing until a "change in the network connection" doesn't interrupt anything.

Comment: What's the [exact laptop model](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PUBLIC_SP4TS_REDIRECTOR/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00033108)? What are the [hardware IDs](http://bit.ly/1jbWdLD) of the Wi-Fi/Ethernet cards? Do you get the same issues if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Answer (score 1):

This might help .. I see it or something similar suggested here and there:

https://ribbalicious.com/fix-windows-8-laptop-dropping-wifi-connection-constantly/

If you have/know someone who has a USB wireless adapter, you could try using that to see if it suffers the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the chipset and wireless card to latest release from the manufacturer website (like Intel).

If your drivers are up to date and the issue is there from the beginning, it might be bad hardware. If not under warranty, I would use a usb WiFi adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only computer that is having the issue.  If not there is the possibility of your problem being a router issue, have you rebooted it recently.  Or if that doesn't work you might try resetting it and also checking the router web site for a update in it's software.

Comment: Yes, this is the only device with this issue. My router works fine on my parents' computer which is the same model. Also, I reboot the router periodically, which usually leads to my third problem mentioned.